# Is there a way to change gpo via a .reg file or batch file?

Tags: group-policy

I share my laptop with my son and I dont want him using the mobile hotspot (Because I cant track it). So I disable it via gpo. See link: https://www.theexperienceblog.com/2016/08/04/how-to-disable-the-mobile-hotspot-feature-in-windows-10-1607-using-gpo-or-mdm/
Can someone please make or tell me how to make a file just to put on my usb so I dont have to go back and forth enabling and disabling? Thanks, Kelby

Comment: Can you do it remotely, while your son's laptop is connected to your home LAN, for example? You open a session as admin (I suppose you're the one who set the PC up in the first place, but I may be wrong), while the laptop is not in use, that is, otherwise you'll kick your son out of his session, which might elicit some vigorous protest... That way, you can access the GPO console, and change whatever setting you want to change. It'll only take a minute. That's what sysadmins do in enterprise networks when a specific issue must be addressed via GPO. Do a "gpudate /force" in admin console after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sysinternals' [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to track down any registry changes.

Below's how I did tracked one specific change:

1. I had GPO open and prepared to do the change
2. I had ProcMon open and set to record

- only Registry changes (see Show Registry Activity in its toolbar) and also
- in its Filter menu had "Drop Filtered Events" checked and
- in its Filter had condition: Detail is "Desired Access: Write"

3. Started to play with GPO changes and checked that ProcMon updates.
4. Stopped ProcMon and double clicked on registry path opened RegEdit from where I could export the new setting in a file.

Summa summarum: the 3 resulted files corresponding to the GPO settings were:

- Not configured:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{DDCB57D9-8C27-430A-8B03-406F86C2F66C}Machine\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Network Connections]
```

- Enabled:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{DDCB57D9-8C27-430A-8B03-406F86C2F66C}Machine\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Network Connections]
"NC_ShowSharedAccessUI"=dword:00000000
```

- Disabled:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{DDCB57D9-8C27-430A-8B03-406F86C2F66C}Machine\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Network Connections]
"NC_ShowSharedAccessUI"=dword:00000001
```

[image: Track Reg Changes]

***Note:*** this was just an example for some GPO, as I couldn't access the **theexperienceblog** link you posted. Hope it helps!